# Android: Elevation missing on button when setting a gradient drawable as background

Tags: android, material-design, elevation

I have a `Button` and I am setting as background a gradient drawable.
The buttons with the gradient drawable are missing the elevation whereas all other buttons have the elevation.

Why is the elevation missing on the buttons with the gradient drawable? And is there any easy way to fix this?

My code looks like this:

gradient.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item>

        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:shape="rectangle">

            <gradient
                android:type="radial"
                android:gradientRadius="250dp"
                android:startColor="@color/blue"
                android:endColor="@color/red"/>

            <corners android:radius="@dimen/round_corner_radius"/>

            <stroke
                android:width="5dp"
                android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>

        </shape>

    </item>

    <item android:top="7dp"
        android:left="7dp"
        android:right="7dp"
        android:bottom="7dp">

        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >

            <solid android:color="#88ffffff"/>
            <corners android:radius="@dimen/round_corner_radius"/>

        </shape>

    </item>

</layer-list>
```

activity.xml

```
...
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button"
        android:background="@drawable/gradient"/>
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem. I had to remove the

```
<stroke
    android:width="5dp"
    android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>
```

The problem was probably the color that was set. Without the stroke the button behaves like a normal raised button.